# Understanding the diagrams of Product and Coproduct

Tags: scala, haskell, tuples, category-theory, either

I am trying to understand the `Product` and `Coproduct` corresponding to the following picture:

Product:
[image]

Coproduct:

[image]

As I understand, a `Product` type in Haskell is for example:

```
data Pair = P Int Double
```

and a `Sum`type is:

```
data Pair = I Int | D Double
```

How to understand the images in relation with `Sum` and `Product` type?

The images are from http://blog.higher-order.com/blog/2014/03/19/monoid-morphisms-products-coproducts/.

Comment: here is some explanation about this topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V10hzjgoklA . Starting at 15 min

Comment: I took the liberty of replacing the word "draw" (by which I imagine you meant "drawing") with the term "diagram", which is what these pictures are called in category theory.

Answer (score 6):

So as far as I can tell, the idea behind these diagrams is that you are given:

- types `A`, `B` and `Z`
- function `f` and `g` of the indicated types (in the first diagram, `f :: Z -> A` and `g :: Z -> B`, in the second the arrows go "the other way", so `f :: A -> Z` and `g :: B -> Z`).

I'll concentrate on the first diagram for now, so that I don't have to say everything twice with slight variations.

Anyway, given the above, the idea is that there is a type `M` together with functions `fst :: M -> A`, `snd :: M -> B`, and `h :: Z -> M` such that, as the mathematicians say, the diagram "commutes". By that is simply meant that, given any two points in the diagram, if you follow the arrows in any way from one to the other, the resulting functions are the same. That is, `f` is the same as  `fst . h` and `g` is the same as `snd . h`

It is easy to see that, no matter what `Z` is, the pair type `(A, B)`, together with the usual Haskell functions `fst` and `snd`, satisfies this - together with an appropriate choice of `h`, which is:

```
h z = (f z, g z)
```

which trivially satisfies the two required identities for the diagram to commute.

That's a basic explanation of the diagram. But you may be slightly confused about the role of `Z` in all this. That arises because what's actually being stated is rather stronger. It is that, given `A`, `B`, `f` and `g`, there is an `M` together with functions `fst` and `snd`, that you can construct such a diagram for *any* type `Z` (which means supplying a function `h :: Z -> M` as well). And further that there is *only one* function `h` which satisfies the required properties.

It's pretty clear, once you play with it and understand the various requirements, that the pair `(A, B)`, and various other types isomorphic to it (which basically means `MyPair A B` where you've defined `data MyPair a b = MyPair a b`), are the only things which satisfy this. And that there are other types `M` which would also work, but which would give various different `h`s - eg. take `M` to be a triple `(A, B, Int)`, with `fst` and `snd` extracting ("projecting to" in mathematical terminology) the first and second components, and then `h z = (f z, g z, x)` is such a function for any `x :: Int` that you care to name.

It's been too long since I studied mathematics, and category theory in particular, to be able to prove that the pair `(A, B)` is the only type that satisfies the "universal property" we're talking about - but rest assured that it is, and you really don't need to understand that (or really any of this) in order to be able to program with product and sum types in Haskell.

The second diagram is more or less the same, but with all the arrows reversed. In this case the "coproduct" or "sum" `M` of `A` and `B` turns out to be `Either a b` (or something isomoprhic to it), and `h :: M -> Z` will be defined as:

```
h (Left a) = f a
h (Right b) = g b
```

Answer (score 5):

A product (`Tuple` in Haskell) is an object with two *projections*. Those are functions *projecting* the product to their individual factors `fst` and `snd`.

Conversly a coproduct (`Either` in Haskell) is an object that has two *injections*. Those are functions *injecting* the individual summands `lefts` and `rights` into the sum.

Note, both product and coproduct need to satisfy an universal property. I recommend Bartosz Milewski's [introduction](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/01/07/products-and-coproducts/) on the topic along with his [lecture](https://youtu.be/Bsdl_NKbNnU).

Answer (score 4):

One thing not communicated by these diagrams is which pieces are inputs and which are outputs. I'm going to start with products and be extra careful about which things are handed to you, and which you must cook up.

So a product says:

1. You give me two objects, A and B.
2. I give you a new object M, and two arrows fst : M -> A and snd : M -> B.
3. You give me an object Z and two arrows f : Z -> A and g : Z -> B.
4. I give you an arrow h : Z -> M that makes the diagram commute (...and this arrow is uniquely determined by the choices made so far).

We often pretend that there is a category Hask in which the objects are concrete (monomorphic) types, and the arrows are Haskell functions of the appropriate type. Let's see how the protocol above plays out, and demonstrate that Haskell's `data Pair a b = P a b` is a product in Hask.

1. You give me two objects (types), A=`a` and B=`b`.
2. I must produce an object (type) and two arrows (functions). I pick M=`Pair a b`. Then I must write functions of type `Pair a b -> a` (for the arrow fst : M -> A) and `Pair a b -> b` (for the arrow snd : M -> B). I choose:

   ```
   fst :: Pair a b -> a
   fst (P a b) = a

   snd :: Pair a b -> b
   snd (P a b) = b
   ```
3. You give me an object (type) Z=`z` and two arrows (functions); `f` will have type `z -> a` and `g` will have type `z -> b`.
4. I must produce a function `h` of type `z -> Pair a b`. I choose:

   ```
   h = \z -> P (f z) (g z)
   ```

   This `h` is required to make the diagram commute. This means that any two paths through the diagram that begin and end at the same object should be equal. For the diagrams given, that means we must show that it satisfies two equations:

   ```
   f = fst . h
   g = snd . h
   ```

   I'll prove the first; the second is similar.

   ```
   fst . h
   = { definition of h }
   fst . (\z -> P (f z) (g z))
   = { definition of (.) }
   \v -> fst ((\z -> P (f z) (g z)) v)
   = { beta reduction }
   \v -> fst (P (f v) (g v))
   = { definition of fst }
   \v -> f v
   = { eta reduction }
   f
   ```

   As required.

The story for coproducts is similar, with the slight tweaks to the protocol described below:

1. You give me two objects, A and B.
2. I give you a new object W, and two arrows left : A -> W and right : B -> W.
3. You give me an object Z and arrows f : A -> Z and g : A -> Z.
4. I give you an arrow h : W -> Z that makes the diagrams commute (...and this arrow is uniquely determined by the choices made so far).

It should be straightforward to adapt the discussion above about products and `Pair` to see how this would apply to coproducts and `data Copair a b = L a | R b`.